# UIView.animate not work correctly in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I Have a function that animates a view's y position. I call this function in tow ways, first as an action target for a button, second by observing a notification. In the first case it works, but in second case when it is called by notification it doesn't animate. the function code is:

```
func showResult() {
    resultMode = true

    self.containerView.frame.origin.y = CGFloat(1000)
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    UIView.animate(
        withDuration: 3,
        animations: {
            self.containerView.frame.origin.y = CGFloat(200)
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    } ,
        completion: nil
    )
}
```

it is called:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.showResult), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "SHOWRESULT"), object: nil)
```

and

```
resultBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.showResult), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: Could you add the code of the 2 cases?

Comment: In case `Notification` call this `showResult ` in main thread

Comment: @AhmadF I added codes to question

Comment: @PratikPrajapati ! thanks it worked!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try triggering notification on main thread

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.showResult), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "SHOWRESULT"), object: nil)
    }
```

**Reason:**

> Regular notification centers deliver notifications on the thread in
>   which the notification was posted. Distributed notification centers
>   deliver notifications on the main thread. At times, you may require
>   notifications to be delivered on a particular thread that is
>   determined by you instead of the notification center. For example, if
>   an object running in a background thread is listening for
>   notifications from the user interface, such as a window closing, you
>   would like to receive the notifications in the background thread
>   instead of the main thread. In these cases, you must capture the
>   notifications as they are delivered on the default thread and redirect
>   them to the appropriate thread.

Answer (score 3):

Tr run modified below `showResult` method:

```
func showResult() {
    resultMode = true

    self.containerView.frame.origin.y = CGFloat(1000)
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        UIView.animate(
            withDuration: 3,
            animations: {
                self.containerView.frame.origin.y = CGFloat(200)
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            } ,
            completion: nil
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had a closure on button tap on which when tapped needed to animate color. Afters hours of frustration calling the animation inside DispatchMain worked the trick

```
copyButton.buttonPressedAction = { [weak self] in
  guard let self = self else {
    return
  }
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.backgroundColor = .green
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {() -> Void in
      self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    })
  }
}
```